# how to developed ocr application with textual image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7.1

i have scan(OCR)  one image  the out put is not correct using Tesseract library.if any one have  idea please share with me. 
i have  write code below

```
Tesseract* tesseract = [[Tesseract alloc] initWithDataPath:@"tessdata" language:@"eng"];
//[tesseract setVariableValue:@"0123456789" forKey:@"tessedit_char_whitelist"];
[tesseract setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"business_card_beauty_salon.jpg"]];
[tesseract recognize];

NSLog(@"%@", [tesseract recognizedText]);
```

OUTPUT is worng
SmMh St
my. 90210
v <
3f»
‘ »' \ .
,, \ *9
Q/ J Q  )@ 
l JaneAnderson Beauty Salon
tel: 905 555 5555

Comment: This is probably one of the worst questions I've seen on here. What is your question? What have you tried? What code Have you got already? Please share a lot more information we will not do your work for you we will just help with issues you are having. Voted to close and -1

Comment: Can you share the image you are trying to scan using OCR ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tesseract is the Open source library . So I dont thing it is much accurate . OCR libraries gives better results for images with resolution more than  150px . Also it would be nice if you give Black and white image . If you are more interested in accuracy then you have to find some paid libraries .

Comment: I wouldn't say this is an answer seems more like a comment

Comment: @Popeye:  Agree ,but initially  I wanted to post some links with the answer and still I am looking for those.

Comment: Thnaks  i am using  http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/OCR_stages/